# HtmlAgilityPack and php tags

Tags: c#, php, tags, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to make out, make changes and save the document with HtmlAgilityPack. But if a document contains php-tags, they go bad when attempting to save. Regular expressions do not want to use, there are many pitfalls. Is there any elegant solution to the problem?

Code:

```
var Doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
Doc.DetectEncodingAndLoad("page.html");
.............
string Result = Doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Source:

```
<html>
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
</html>
```

Result:

```
<html>
<?php echo="" "hello";=""?>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you wanting to modify PHP source files as HTML?

Comment: I have templates with php-includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported today, but you can fix it if you change the source and recompile (after all, this is what open source is for...). Go to HtmlNode.cs, find the `internal void WriteAttributes(TextWriter outText, bool closing)` function, and add the following piece of code:

```
internal void WriteAttributes(TextWriter outText, bool closing)
{
    if (Name.StartsWith("?"))
    {
        int len = _outerlength - 3 - _namelength;
        if (len > 0)
        {
            outText.Write(OwnerDocument.Text.Substring(_namestartindex + _namelength, len));
            return;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: The problem is that htmlagilitypack understands "<?php" just as one unclosed tag, and the decision will still be a multi-line script to spoil.
Regex - a good solution, but they will not work if a php-code contains "?>"(for example: echo "<?xml...?>";).

Comment: I don't understand. If you modify Html Agility Pack source like I say, it answers your question. If you have another problem, create another question.